# How to resolve promises and catch an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to user `webgazer.js` where my code basically checks to see whether the `webgazer` is initialized and when it is initialized it resolves a promise which dispatches an action. This works however if for example there is no webcam I need to throw an error. The error in my code never gets called.

Here is my code

```
export function detectJsCamera() {
    return async(dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type: types.JS_DETECTING_CAMERA});
        try {
            await detectCamera();
            await dispatch({type: types.JS_CAMERA_DETECTED});
        } catch (error) {
            await dispatch({type: types.CAMERA_DETECTION_FAILED, error: error.message});
            throw error;
        // this.props.history.push('/setup/positioning')
    };
    }
}

const detectCamera = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const checkIfReady = () => {
        if (webgazer.isReady()) {
        resolve('success');
        } else {
            console.log('called')
        setTimeout(checkIfReady, 100);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(checkIfReady,100);
});
```

Comment: you need to call reject() so an error from promise is thrown, dispatch is not an async call

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reject in order to throw an exception like below

```
const detectCamera = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const checkIfReady = () => {
        if (webgazer.isReady()) {
            resolve('success');
        } else {
            console.log('called');
            reject("some error");
        }
    }
    setTimeout(checkIfReady,100);
});
```

Comment: Only problem is that it takes a while for webgazer to initialise so the promise will be rejected before it can be resolved?

Comment: thats why you have `webgazer.isReady()` to check if its ready I guess. You will somehow need to make sure if webgazer is Ready()

Answer (score 0):

You need to call **reject()** in your detectCamera method when your webgazer is not initialised then it would be caught in your catch block in detectJsCamera method.